# Is there a way to stop a flare animation from looping?

Tags: animation, flutter

I am making an application where I'm trying out flare animations. I have a custom animation and it works as intended. Except that the animation is looping repeatedly whereas i want it to play once and freeze the last frame.

I've tried using the FlareControls() class but I haven't had any luck. I've also tried setting the callback param to a function that sets "paused" to true but that didn't work either since isPaused is a final variable. I've also tried the callback parameter to print test in order to indicate that the animation was finished but it didn't work

```dart
FlareActor(
      "assets/flares/checkmark.flr",
      animation: "Checkmark",
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      shouldClip: false,
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      snapToEnd: true,
      callback: (value){
        print("test");
//        flare.animation = "idle";
      },
```

With the snippet included, I'm expecting a message on the console to print test when the loop's finished but to no avail

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Flare website when creating your animation, click the button next to your animation timeline in the bottom left, so that it is disabled. Now you export the new file and replace the old one in your assets.